# Plumbing a 60inch double vanity with one or two p traps

Tags: p-trap

Here is my layout. I have one drain on the right side of the vanity coming through the floor. If I come up to TEE WYE Going to The left sink with a pipe run that is 40 inches hooking to a p-trap then to The sink drain. For the right side drain, I would add another TEE WYE on top of the other one with a p-trap hooking to the right side, and on top of the TEE WYE would be a siphon valve would this cause issues? I have pictures of my set up not sure how to post them any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would strongly suggest a real vent, rather than a AAV (air admittance valve) that I assume is what you mean by "siphon valve" - the stinky truth about AAVs is that they fail, and things stink. A double tee simplifies the layout.

Comment: ...And yes, you need two traps if it's more than 30" between multiple sink drains. You can [edit] your post and add picture links (imgur tends to work best) - I think as a brand new user you can inline one (use the "mountain and sun" icon) which loads them to imgur - when you get a bit more rep you can load multiples - for now, if you paste in the links someone else can edit those in for you. Take the [tour]